# Javascript String(['a', 'b', 'c']) and `${['a', 'b', 'c']}` difference

Tags: javascript

When convert "string array" to "string".

- `var a = String(['a', 'b', 'c'])`
- `` var a = `${['a', 'b', 'c']}` ``

What is difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is none. `String(someExpression)` is identical to:

```
`${someExpression}`
```

But template literals are generally used only when you need to do a bit more than cast something to a string - like to interpolate an expression into the middle of something else in a string, eg:

```
`foo${['a', 'b', 'c'}]`
```

in order to result in

```
fooa,b,c
```

Otherwise, if you just have a single expression to turn into a string, using `String` may be a bit clearer that you're only casting a *single expression* to a string, rather than doing anything else, and so may look a bit less confusing to some than using a template literal.

Answer (score 0):

There is almost no difference.

Useful references:

- [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)
- [String primitives and objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_primitives_and_String_objects)

One thing to notice is that a primitive string is produced by using `String` without `new`, while an object is produced by using `new String()`.